# in class constructor this.button = document.getElementById('button') / Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

I got my webpack bundle with some bunch of code:

```
class View extends EventEmitter {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.input = document.getElementById('input');
        this.btn = document.getElementById('button');
        this.list = document.getElementById('list');
    }
    addListeners() {
        this.btn.addEventListener('click',this.emit('some', this.inputValue));
    }
   // some other stuff
}

//--------got error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

but when i'm doing :

```
addListeners() {

// document.getElementById('button') instead of this.btn everything is good 


document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',this.emit('some', this.inputValue));
    }
```

Comment: If the `class` instantiation happens before the DOM is built, the elements won't be found.

Comment: Where do you construct your `View` and where do you call `addListeners()` ?

Comment: I got 3 js modules : Model , View , Controller . In Controller i'm creating a new View 
entity and put it in Controller constructor  , then i call it in Controller's init method , in index.js I'm creating Controller entity and call controller.init() /  I'm making ToDo app , on MVC pattern with using pub/sub pattern , so I need emit ''myEvent' by click , then Controller got a method that is listening to this event and send to Model some info about context of added ToDo item , and then run render method to render new item on View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the context. In your addListeners method, put inside

```
console.log(this);
```

to see what context is inside this function. It may be pointing not to what you expect.

Also, to add event listener you do this:

```
this.btn.addEventListener('click',this.emit);
```

With your current code you execute function once, you don't add event listener.

Comment: so , how should I add an event on every click ?

Comment: addListeners() {
        this.btn.addEventListener('click',this.emit);
    }                                                                                                                        
You add listener only one time. And it will listen in the background.

Answer (score 1):

When the constructor is called, the DOM was not yet fully created,  so `this.btn` points to nothing.  This is why you can't add an event listener to it.

You could try to make sure the DOM is created before you initialize your class, by wrapping your code in `window.onload = func_that_wraps_your_use_of_View()`

Comment: This isn't a question about React.

Comment: @Andy True,  but his code is in React, so the solution should take that into account

Comment: I got my project on vanilla JS , not React

Comment: @IgorKliuchnik ahh sorry! the syntax was very similar so I assumed.  updated my answer to pure JS, hope it helps